# How can I get macOS to update view of file size for files in Dropbox? (it *IS* possible!)

Tags: macos, dropbox

Sometime in the last year or so (?), Apple made a nasty change to how cloud-based directories are handled on the Mac.  (I'm on Monterey.)
It used to be that if "Dropbox" was "mounted" as ~/Dropbox, then I could (from Terminal) do an "ls -l" of the directory and see the size (EOF) of every file.

Now, the vast majority of files show up as 0 bytes.

Dropbox support has been no help ... simply saying "Apple made a change".

If I (from Terminal or a command-line C program I write) access a file, I usually see the file as empty.  I.e, "open ()" and "fopen()" functions are not seeing the real file information, and think the files are empty (as does stat() and fstat()).

BUT... and this matters ...

If I do "open foo.txt" (from Terminal, where "foo.txt" is a Dropbox file), then TextEdit starts up *AND SEES THE FILE DATA*.  Also, everyone can now see the file size, including "ls -l" and open() and fopen() etc!   (And, this information persists across a reboot!)

I.e., *SOMETHING* is being done TextEdit to trigger macOS to ask Dropbox how big the file is.

I've lost the fight with Dropbox support to get them to fix the problem (and they had several approaches I outlined, including fighting with Apple or using FUSE).

So....I'd like to know: *what function* (if any) can I call from a C program to trigger the update of the file information?
E.g., is TextEdit using some variant of "open" that I could call?

If knew that function, I could write a utility to trigger the update on all my files :)

(BTW, I did not tag this post as "dropbox-api" because it's not relevant to the Dropbox API.)

thanks!

BTW, according to DTrace, these are the system calls made during the time I did an "open" of a file (that had shown up as 0 bytes, but has data) ... well, they're the ones that look like they have some vague possibility of being of interest (e.g., I excluded things like getpid())  (Each is followed by a number, which is the number of times the function was called.)  After the 'open', the file size is visible (from another window).

> __mac_syscall                                                   163   access                                                           12
> faccessat                                                         3
> fcntl                                                             4
> ffsctl                                                            9
> fgetattrlist                                                      1
> fgetxattr                                                         4
> fsgetpath                                                        28
> fstat64                                                          21
> fstatat64                                                         3
> fstatfs64                                                         9
> getattrlist                                                     118
> getattrlistbulk                                                   2
> getdirentries64                                                   6
> getxattr                                                         11
> guarded_open_np                                                   1
> ioctl                                                             1
> lstat64                                                           2
> mmap                                                             41
> open                                                             28
> open_nocancel                                                    17
> stat64                                                           37
> statfs64                                                         10
> sysctl                                                            8
> sysctlbyname                                                      1

Comment: In DropBox Preferences in Sync is 'New files default' set to 'online-only'?

Comment: @JonathanDodds yes.   As dropbox help says, "online only" means that the file gets copied to your harddrive when you access it [via a supported Apple app, apparently].  If you want to use a "third party app" you have to mark it as "available offline" (?), which *copies it to your hard drive".  [argh, can't hit <return>]  This is a marked difference from prior macOS versions, which access them more like NFS or Samba (as, indeed, ought to be the case :)   No guidance is provided as to how long copied files stay on your hard drive, sigh.  (Nor is info provided on how to clean them up)